# Azure Red Hat OpenShift requires a minimum of 40 cores to create and run an OpenShift cluster

Tags: azure, redhat, openshift-online-2, azure-devops-server

0

I am trying to deploy ARO azure redhat openshift cluster but it get failing stating The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state ResourceQuotaExceeded Resource quota of cores exceeded. Maximum allowed: 21, Current in use: 2, Additional requested: 36

Is 40 cores compulsory for this ARO cluster deployment?

https://developers.redhat.com/articles/2022/03/04/create-azure-red-hat-openshift-cluster-less-5-minutes#set_up_azure_red_hat_openshift

Answer (score 0):

To run RH OpenShift you need Master node, workers (where the pods run), storage. So this requirement (40 cores) is very reasonable.Check in documentation how many, what kind of nodes are required in Azure.

Comment: yes as i am doing POC in subscription where my teammates don't want to increase quota so i posted thanks Romeo

Comment: @esngsrj, if you have some free local machines you can create the POC locally.